# Is inheriting from the EventEmitter an antipattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class, eventemitter, anti-patterns

It appears to be common practice to inherit from the EventEmitter if you want your class to support events.
For example Google does it for [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/49f25e2412fbe3ac43ebc6913a582718066486cc/experimental/puppeteer-firefox/lib/Browser.js#L6), the [WebSocket module](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/a2c0d447af711ca245cb534159fa7c4d9ae67e64/lib/websocket.js#L35) does it, [mongoose does it](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/b4e0ae52a57b886bc7046d38332ce3b38a2f9acd/index.d.ts#L169), ... just to name a few.

But is this really good practice? I mean sure it looks nice and clean, but from an OOP perspective it seems wrong. For example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')
class Rectangle extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(x,y,w,h) {
        super()
        this.position = {x:x, y:y}
        this.dimensions = {w:w, h:h}
    }
    setDimensions(w,h) {
        this.dimensions = {w:w, h:h}
        this.emit('dimensionsChanged')
    }
}
```

would make it seem like Rectangle is an EventEmitter at its core even though the eventing functionality is secondary.

What if you decide that `Rectangle` now needs to inherit from a new class called `Shape`?

```
class Shape {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.position = {x:x, y:y}
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    constructor(x,y,w,h) {
        super(x,y)
        this.dimensions = {w:w, h:h}
    }
}
```

Now you would have to make `Shape` inherit from the EventEmitter. Even if only one class inheriting from `Shape` actually needs eventing.

Wouldn't something like this make way more sense?

```
class Shape {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.position = {x, y}
    }
}

const EventEmitter = require('events')

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    constructor(x,y,w,h) {
        super(x,y)
        this.dimensions = {w, h}
        this.em = new EventEmitter()
    }
    setDimensions(w,h) {
        this.dimensions = {w:w, h:h}
        this.em.emit('dimensionsChanged')
    }
}

const rectangle = new Rectangle(1,2,3,4)
rectangle.em.on('dimensionsChanged', ()=>{console.log('dimensions changed')})
rectangle.setDimensions(10,20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely makes more sense.

Inheritance should be used to denote *is a* relationships: `class Rectangle extends Shape` is ok since `Rectangle` is a shape, but here the rectangle itself *is not an* `EventEmitter`.

Instead, we have an *can* relationship: `Rectangle` *can emit an event*, and that is exactly where you should favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), which is what happens in your last code snippet.

We can only speculate as to why some famous libs don't do that - retro-compatibility, simplicity of APIs, or simply bad design.